# Name of Microsoft's Build in Criteria Queries?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Some time ago I read that one of Microsoft's (supported) Programming languages seems to have an Abstraction of SQL that translates them into generic Criteria that are not bound to SQL.

These Criteria are rather "generic" in a sense that it's easy to do implementations to query any datastore. Its a programming-language inherent abstration of SQL.

How is this technic/standard/pattern/api exactly called? I can not find it anymore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about Linq (Language INtegrated Query).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query

Comment: Great! Yes that was I was searching for! Thanks!